# GitLab v5.0 git push problems

Tags: git, ubuntu-12.04, ssh-keys, gitlab

I'm creating this question to help others in their search for documentation regarding two GitLab configuration problems when attempting to push an initialized repo:

**1: the git user on your GitLab server requires password even after setting up an SSH Key in the GitLab frontend:**

```
$ git push -u origin master
git@hostname's password:
```

**2: the gitlab-shell client seems to look in the wrong place for your repo when attempting to push (`/home/git/repositories` is where all repositories should be stored as specified in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`):**

```
$ git push -v -u origin master
Pushing to git@hostname:sadmicrowave/test-project.git
fatal: 'sadmicrowave/test-project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: 5.0 is very, very, very old at this very moment. Please consider an update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the SSH Key got added in the GitLab frontend I noticed it was not being added accordingly in the `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  After some digging I found this https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3120 which points out to run the following rake:

```
rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

*Note: the reference leaves out the part `RAILS_EVN=production` but that is required so you don't get another error stating `cannot load such file -- rb-inotify`*

As my git user does not have `sudo` access I had to run the above command from another user login with sudo and then run the following to give the proper permissions (git) back to the .ssh directory:

```
$ sudo chgrp -R git /home/git/.ssh
$ sudo chown -R git /home/git/.ssh
```

After all that, go back to the GitLab frontend, delete and recreate your SSH-Key (you can use the same public key as before).

You should see the correct record in `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` and if you run `git push -v -u origin master` from your local machine you should be good now!

Comment: hopefully this saves someone hours of searching

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113047/coping-with-gitlab-ssh-key-syncronization-bug)

Comment: Little typo at sudo chgrp -R git /home/git/.ssh .