# gitlab-shell push fatal error

Tags: git, gitlab

I am having problem in getting my initial repo pushed to gitlabhq server using gilab-shell. Earlier I had setup gitlabhq (2.1) + gitolite that is working fine.

```
ssh -T git@git.domain.net
Welcome to GitLab 5.2, Anonymous!
```

But when I try to push anything

```
git push -u origin master
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I checked across many answers in stackover flow and the issue list of gitlab but non of them seems to help me.

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues

[GitLab v5.0 git push problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179366/gitlab-v5-0-git-push-problems)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gitlabhq/dqiHDBrXOjQ/PEntFiYxTGUJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. The issue turn out to be with gitlab url.

So it was not issue more of a configuration setup. The config.yml of gitlab-shell should correctly point the URL. In my case it was http://git.domain.com:9222/.

Also, I use RVM for all ruby stuff, so make sure change all ruby binary path in gitlab config files from /usr/bin/ruby to $HOME/.rvm/bin/ruby.

Answer (score 0):

$ git config --global user.name "Your Name Comes Here"
$ git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.example.com

First type the above commands with your username as email and password.

then type these line of code
$ git init
$ git add .

then type the command it will work.

Comment: Did the same but same issue. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly