# Coping with gitlab ssh key syncronization bug

Tags: configuration, rake, ssh-keys, gitlab

I attempted to use a solution posted here: [GitLab v5.0 git push problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179366/gitlab-v5-0-git-push-problems) to fix the ssh keys getting out of sync problem.

However, when I run the `rake` command as both `root` & `git` users on the repository server I get the following message:

```
root@gitlab /home/git# rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production --TRACE

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

How is the `rake` command supposed to be used to fix the synchronization problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be similar to [this issue 3922](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3922):

> You must execute this command in the GitLab installation directory containing the Rakefile

So make sure to go in the gitlab directory where you can see [the `Rakefile`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/Rakefile).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `rake` now runs but it says: `Don't know how to build task 'gitlab:shell:setup'`

Comment: @awashburn I thought it might. It could be obsolete now, and replaced by gitlab-shell.